# Widget Bar at bottom of page

Tags: css

Hello I've been modifying the CSS a lot on my site lately.  Maybe because of this, my widgets bar is now at the bottom of my page.  I've looked through previous posts on this topic which say the problem could be related to either faulty html in posts or faulty css.  The problem came about when I was modifying my CSS, so I have tried expanding my page width, modifying my widget bar size, and making smaller the size of posts to fix the problem, but all to no avail.  I've been putting in lots of hours on my own to fix this problem and am only coming here as a last resort.

My site is http://www.diveintonewenglish.com.  If anyone could help me it would be really great, and
perhaps helpful to people with similar problems.

Comment: And where do you want it to be? It may be good that you add an image/sketch with the desired layout. Otherwise, is hard to help you.

Comment: Hello.  Originally it was to the side of the posts on my site's main page.  My word press template, expound, breaks the site's main page into a main post at top, four secondary posts right below, and then "older posts" which are at the bottom.  Originally the widget bar was to the right side of the "older posts."  I would like to return it to here, or to the side of the secondary posts division if  possible.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (posts 75% of the width, widget bar 25%):

```
#primary {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 75%;
}
#secondary {
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  width: 25%;
}
.widget-area {
  padding: 0;
}
/* and remove styles of DIV#secondary.widget-area */
```

Comment: Ok so I have the code in now exactly as you said and removed the div#secondary.widget-area.  There is a nice little pocket where the widget bar could go, but it's not moving into that pocket.  I am going to keep the code in so that you can tell me if there are any other mistakes.... Thank you so much with your help so far

Comment: There is another definition of the #secondary class that is overwriting the previous one. This is the resource which is messing with it: http://diveintonewenglish.com/?custom-css=1&csblog=1&cscache=6&csrev=18
So, you should remove the #secondary class from there